# Performance issues when mirroring ipad to vga output

Tags: ipad, mirroring

I have tried various techniques for mirroring my ipad application to vga output, but am getting very bad performance.

Is there a better or worse way of doing this?

Comment: Need more information.  The question is unanswerable in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123

[Rob Terrell's TVOutManager](https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager) is the solution.

The next line is all your need:  `[[TVOutManager sharedInstance] startTVOut];`